# Scatter plot having various features contrast with one multiclass target

Tags: python, plot, scatter-plot

I have a dataset with a dimension of (20, 100000), and there is one target feature with 5 different classes,
I would like to make a scatter plot for all the classes considering all the features, with different colors for each class.

here is the code

```
x= train_df.drop(['y'], axis=1)
y=train_df['y']

features = x
target = y.values.ravel()

plt.scatter(x, y, label="Face clusters", color='k', s=10)
```

But getting an error that the dimension of x and y is not equal.
How can I solve it?

Comment: `plt.scatter` expects `x` and `y` to correspond to Cartesian coordinates, where `x` is the list of *abscissa* of the points, also called the x-coordinates, and `y` is the list of *ordinates* of the points, also called the y-coordinates. The result would be a 2d-scatterplot. But you've said yourself that you had waaaaaay more than 2 dimensions. I suggest using colours for the classes rather than the y-coordinate; and choosing only two of the input features to be the x- and y-coordinates in the scatterplot. Choose the two most relevant features.

Comment: Or instead of using the two most relevant features, you could perform [PCA](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.PCA.html) and use the two most relevant "principal components".